# GEMSET disappears from APP when Closing Aptana + RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, aptana

I am currently using the latest version of AptanaStudio3 and I am running into an annoying issue.

Every time I am done working with my app and I close the app out, when I revisit it at a later time, my gemset is completely gone, forcing me to re-install everything! Aptana shows no gemsets exist in the directory.

I'm using RVM without a problem and able to verify that the GEMSET still exists on my HD.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?